# Wordpress search field affecting custom query

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Just came across an issue with my Wordpress template that I can't figure out.  I am using a custom built menu (done simply with a quick query_posts() call), but when searching for certain terms, my query is affected.  Not a clue as to why.

Here's my menu code:

```
<?php $main_cats=explode(",",$options['main_cats']); ?> 
<?php $myargs = array('post_type' => 'page', 'post__in'=>$main_cats,'order'=>'ASC'); ?>
<?php query_posts($myargs);
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
```

This should end up with 4 menu items.  However, when searching for a few "job" related items, it seems that the Job Manager plugin steps in (http://pento.net/projects/wordpress-job-manager-plugin/) and I get one menu result stating "This job doesn't exist".  However, I don't understand how that plugin could possible affect my query.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code assume that $main_cats has the right data, before testing this, check that the variable is correct:

```
<?php 
$main_cats=explode(",",$options['main_cats']);
$menu_items=get_posts(array('post_type' => 'page', 'post__in'=>$main_cats,'order'=>'ASC'));
foreach($menu_items as $menu_item){ ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($menu_item->ID); ?>"><?php echo $menu_item->post_title; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Maybe Use native menu function to  to create menu's, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu
2. Don't use query_posts($myargs), query_posts() is meant for altering the main loop.
   Use `WP QUERY` http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query  (or get_posts).

Comment: Updated query_posts to use WP_Query, but nothing changed.  Here is the page in question: http://www.norfolkcounty.ca/?s=test&submit=

Answer (score 0):

Try `wp_reset_query();` before your query as well as after, like you have.  I think that the plugin query is happening before your yours.  There may be some carry over from that.  Reseting before your query might give you a clean slate.

Comment: Tried that as well, but doesn't change anything.